# GTM- data layer not populating while in preview mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

I enabled preview mode in GTM to debug and I dont see anything populate in data layer. It was fine until yesterday but it is showing undefined currently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug - see users also posting here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/B6D272wYOUs;context-place=forum/tag-manager